# Assign value to a Dataframe from a list of tuple depending on the column of it

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of tuple containing the first element which is people's name and the second one responsible for their scores

```
[(A, 1), (B,2), (C,3).....]
```

And my df has a column filled with the same names. How can I create a new column with their scores accordingly?

Comment: Please do some googling before asking questions and read the documentation properly `df = pd.DataFrame([('A', 1), ('B',2), ('C',3)])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way-

```py
# Let's say variable df is your dataframe, and variable data is the tuple

new_dict = {k[0]:k[1] for k in data}
df['score'] = [new_dict[name] for name in df['names'] if name in new_dict.keys() else None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `l` your list and `df['name']` your DataFrame column, use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on the list converted to dictionary:

```
df['score'] = df['name'].map(dict(l))
```

Example:

```
l = [('A', 1), ('B',2), ('C',3)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['C', 'X', 'A']})

df['score'] = df['name'].map(dict(l))
```

Output:

```
  name  score
0    C    3.0
1    X    NaN
2    A    1.0
```